# Set DIV tag visibility in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, json.net

My jQuery code is

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "~/Pages/test.aspx",
        data: "json",
        success: function (response) {

            $('#testSpan').html(response.HasCases);

    },
        error: function (e1, e2, e3) {
            $('#testSpan').html('Error');
    }
});
```

I am getting response value as True or False.If my value is True I should display the DIV tag vale else I should  hide the DIV tag.The above code displayed as true or false values in the place of div text :(.

Answer (score 1):

toggle will show or hide element based on Boolean value.

```
 $('#testSpan').toggle(response.HasCases);
```

reference:

[**toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `show()` and `hide()` instead of html()

```
if(response.HasCases == "true")
   $('#testSpan').show();
else 
  $('#testSpan').hide();
```

Your code would be

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "~/Pages/test.aspx",
        data: "json",
        success: function (response) {       
          if(response.HasCases == "true")
             $('#testSpan').show();  
        }, error: function (e1, e2, e3){   
            $('#testSpan').show();           
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [**toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) to acheive this:

```
if(response.HasCases == "true")
   $('#testSpan').toggle();
```